# Equivalent strconv in Advantage SQL DB

Tags: sql, string, advantage-database-server

I am converting an access query that updates fields from ALL CAPS to Basically normal First Letter Capital, rest lower case.  In access ive used strconv
Ive havent found a similar function in advantage sql db.  Ive found upper and lcase, but those dont seem to work for me.

StrConv([City],3)

An import process brings in all caps to a field called City.  So City Comes in as CHICAGO, my end result would be Chicago, and this works in access using strconv,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement should work: `SELECT Upper( Left( [field], 1 ) ) + Lower( SubString( [field], 2, Length( [field] )-1 ) ) FROM CustomersTbl`

Answer (score 0):

Never used advantage but a quick Google suggests something like the following should work.

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(field, 1, 1), LOWER(SUBSTRING(field, 2, LENGTH(field) - 1)))
```

Comment: When i insert my field name "CITY" into the string you provided, its not changing anything, its basically just doing nothing.  I am very new to advantage, but not new to sql.  I do not like some of the sytax being used vs microsoft sql

Comment: Drop the " marks? Like I said I've never used advantage.

Comment: Ok, try breaking things down, does SUBSTRING(field, 1, 1) return the first character of your field? Can you CONCAT two strings together? Build from there.

Comment: SUBSTRING(field,1,1) returns first letter.  I will work on putting things together.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Advantage doesn't have a `StrConv` function, but there are a few ways to do the same thing.

I've used a scripting variable in this code segment to emulate the field. You can replace all instances of `cityname` with the name of your database column (field). Pick the one you like. `system.iota` is a one-row system database that can be used in Advantage when you don't want to use a real table for testing functions. Of course, you'd replace it with your actual table name in your own code. You can run each of the sample select statements (individually) in the Advantage Database Utility to test them; pick the one that seems the cleanest to you, as they're all the same as far as performance goes. (NOTE: `UCase()` and `UpperCase()` are the exact same functions internally; they both exist simply because some users expect to find `UCase()` and others `UpperCase()` depending on the programming language they're using. The same is true of `LCase()` and `LowerCase()`.)

I've intentionally used a mixed bag of UPPER/lower case letters in the variable `cityname` below to demonstrate that the actual case doesn't matter; the statements provided will produce a proper-cased (first letter upper, rest lower) result.

```
declare cityname string;
set cityname = 'cHIcAGo';

-- Method 1
select 
  UCase(Substring(cityname, 1, 1)) + LCASE(SubString(cityname, 2, Length(cityname))) as city
from system.iota

-- Method 2
select
  UpperCase(Left(cityname, 1)) + LowerCase(SubString(cityname, 2, Length(cityname)) as city
from system.iota

-- Method 3
select 
  UCase(Left(cityname, 1)) + LCase(Right(cityname, Length(city) - 1)) as city
from system.iota
```